# (AFNetworking) how to adjust a header in an AFHTTPRequestOperation request?

Tags: swift, afnetworking, afhttprequestoperation

How can I modify an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` header after creating it? In situations where an API request returns a `401`, i need to refresh the access token and adjust every `AFHTTPRequestOperation`'s header, and retry the *same* request operation with the updated access token.

Below is my code to process requests that were queued due to an access token is currently being refreshed. When a new access token is received, this method is called.

The method below works, but it just seems odd that creating a new variable of the operation request and adjusting the variable's header also changes the original request.

```
var authManager = AFOAuth2Manager()

func processHeldRequests() {
        for operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation in heldRequests {
            var token = tokenManager.getToken()
            println("adjusting held operation's request header authorization to new token \(token!)")

            var operationRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = operation.request as! NSMutableURLRequest
            operationRequest.setValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            authManager.operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
        }
        heldRequests.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    }
```